# My Xquery results keep returning a blank

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery

I have the following query where I assign the @input variable an xml column from a table. I've ignored the namespace but I'm not getting any results..... Can anyone please help?

Here's the example Xml and then the query......

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<FIXML xmlns="http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4"xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">-
<Batch>-
<AllocInstrctn PosEfct="C" NetMny="000000" BkngTyp="0" SettlDt="2014-05-15" SettlTyp="0"TxnTm="2014-05-15T10:53:28+01:00" TrdDt="2014-05-15" Ccy="GBP" AvgPx="0" PxTyp="9" OrignDt="2014-05-15" QtyTyp="0" Qty="0000000" Side="2" NoOrdsTyp="1" LinkTyp="1" LinkID="0000000SE" ID2="1000000" Typ="1" TransTyp="0" ID="0000000"><Hdr TID="HSS" SID="AER_TFOLIO"/>
</AllocInstrctn>
</Batch>
</FIXML>


declare @Trade_Ref nvarchar(12)

select  @Trade_Ref = 'XYZ'

declare @input xml =    (
    select  FIXML_Data
    from    dbo.OTC_FIXML_Data
    where   TradeRef = @Trade_Ref
    )
;with XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://')                      
SELECT  @input.value('TrdDt[1]', 'datetime') 
FROM    @input.nodes('/Batch/AllocInstrctn') AS rep(AllocInstrctn)
```

Comment: What part of the XQuery doesnt return results, the part in the FROM clause, of the part in the SELECT clause? I.e. what happens if you put a * in the SELECT clause?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4') 
SELECT  @input.value('(/FIXML/Batch/AllocInstrctn/@TrdDt)[1]', 'datetime')
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ignore a namespace by not declaring it, it's in the data. Either also ignore it in the query, or declare and use it. Ignoring is possible by using the wildcard namespace `*`:

```
/*:Batch/*:AllocInstrctn
```

Also it seems you're omitting the outermost XML node, `<FIXML/>`.

```
/*:FIXML/*:Batch/*:AllocInstrctn
```

Your XML is not well-formed anyway, as the root element may not be preceded by (among others) text nodes (the `-` may not  be there). Maybe SQL Server is able to deal with that, but if that really is the content you've got to deal with you should complain at whoever sends that data.

Comment: No chance, comes from a Portfolio management system. Thanks for the help, new to this.

Answer (score 0):

I Tried using this, see if it helps you

```
Declare @xml XML
SET @xml = N'
<FIXML>
<Batch>
<AllocInstrctn PosEfct="C" NetMny="000000" BkngTyp="0" SettlDt="2014-05-15" SettlTyp="0" TxnTm="2014-05-15T10:53:28+01:00" TrdDt="2014-05-15" Ccy="GBP" AvgPx="0" PxTyp="9" OrignDt="2014-05-15" QtyTyp="0" Qty="0000000" Side="2" NoOrdsTyp="1" LinkTyp="1" LinkID="0000000SE" ID2="1000000" Typ="1" TransTyp="0" ID="0000000"><Hdr TID="HSS" SID="AER_TFOLIO"/>
</AllocInstrctn>
</Batch>
</FIXML>'
SELECT T.Item.value('@PosEfct', 'VARCHAR(50)') PosEfct,
        T.Item.value('@TrdDt', 'DATETIME') TrdDt
 FROM @xml.nodes('/FIXML/Batch/AllocInstrctn') AS T(Item)
```